# Why are my nails not symmetric (shorter on left hand)?

Tags: fingers, nails

Some time ago, I noticed that my nails on the left hand look "shorter" than those on the right hand: there seems to be more skin on the "lower" part of the finger nails on the left hand. Here are a few photos to help you understand.

1. Both hands
   [image: mains]
2. Middle fingers  (left/right) [image]
3. Ring fingers    (left/right) [image]

I did not ask my doctor about this, since it is not a major issue. I have no known pathology which could explain this strange phenomenon. Any ideas?

Note: I am "right-handed" (i.e., I write with the right hand).

Comment: Do you happen to play a stringed instrument like the guitar or violin? Has it always been like this, or could it be a development due to behavior/environment?

Comment: I play the piano as an amateur (so just a few hours a week, not that much). I don't remember having this as a child or a teenager.

Comment: I've not encountered any data on this specifically, but in myself, I'm a righty and my *left* nails, hand, foot and leg are bigger (and that side of my face). Some work has been done on [handedness and facial asymmetry](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13836362_Facial_Asymmetry_in_Right-_and_Left-Handed_Men_and_Women) which you might find interesting, but it's not a direct answer to your question.

Comment: One possibility is that, if you're a nail biter, you bite your nails on the left hand more than the right. Whatever the case, anything that causes you to constantly trim your nails short will shorten the total nail bed length.

Comment: @anongoodnurse : I am not biting my nails, not cutting them more on the left hand than on the right one. Note that they are shorter on the left because of the "lower part" of the nail.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Doesn't that have anything to do with Genetics?

Comment: I don't know, I don't even know if it's known. Lots of things are suspected, sure (handedness being almost 100% genetic), but until someone publishes a study with a big enough sample of genetic material and the rest (and tells us about it), we can only guess. @SnackExchange (I should realy say : "make educated guesses based on the knowns and uncertainties").